# [Symfony][FOSUserBundle] Authentification from bootstrap modal / Lost Session

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, symfony

I got a bug with the FOSUserBundle that make me crazy :

I use a bootstrap modal for the authentification, like this :

```
<div class="modal fade" id="modalLogin" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-body"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And i load the modal-body with an Ajax Request linked to the FOS login URL (fos_user_security_login) :

```
$(".connectModal").bind("click", function() {
$.ajax({
    url: $('#path_login').val(),
    success: function (data) {
        $('#modalLogin .modal-body').html(data);
        $('#modalLogin').modal()
    }
});
```

});

Then, in my modal, i use Ajax to check authentication. So i use :

```
$('#form_login').submit( function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      e.stopImmediatePropagation();
      $.ajax({
          url: {{ path("fos_user_security_check") }},
          type: "post",
          data: {_csrf_token: $('#csrf_token').val(), _username: $('#username').val(), _password: $('#password').val(), _remember_me: 'on'},
          dataType: 'json',
          complete: function (data, statut) {
              if (statut == 'success') {
                  $('#modalLogin').modal('hide');
              }
          },
          error : function(resultat, statut, error){
              $('#error_message').text(JSON.parse(resultat.responseText).message);
              $('#error_block').show();
          }
      });
  });
```

Everything works great ! If the authentication fails, i get error and display it. If the authentication is ok, i get the user in the Symfony session (i can check it in the Symfony's debug console).

But once i close my modal, the authenticated user isn't propagate in the website's session (is there a different one ?!?). I stay in an anonymous state... :(
And i really don't where to investigate no more... Is that a problem from Symfony? FOSUserBundle? JQuery?

To finish, here are my security firewall :

```
profil:
        pattern: ^/account/
        security: true
        provider: fos_userbundle
        context: _security_login
        form_login:
            login_path: fos_user_security_login
            check_path: fos_user_security_check
            csrf_token_generator: security.csrf.token_manager
            success_handler: juser.success_handler
            failure_handler: juser.failure_handler
            default_target_path: /account
        logout:
            path: fos_user_security_logout
            target: /
        remember_me:
            key: "%secret%"
            lifetime: 86400
```

My Success Handler :

```
    <?php

namespace JUserBundle\Handler;


use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\TokenInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authentication\DefaultAuthenticationSuccessHandler;
use Symfony\Component\Translation\TranslatorInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\HttpUtils;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\RouterInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

class AuthenticationSuccessHandler extends DefaultAuthenticationSuccessHandler
{
    /**
     * Router
     * @var \Symfony\Component\Routing\RouterInterface
     */
    private $router;

    /**
     * Translator
     * @var \Symfony\Component\Translation\TranslatorInterface
     */
    private $translator;

    /**
     * AuthenticationSuccessHandler constructor.
     * @param HttpUtils $httputils
     * @param RouterInterface $router
     * @param TranslatorInterface $translator
     */
    public function __construct(HttpUtils $httputils, RouterInterface $router, TranslatorInterface $translator)
    {
        parent::__construct($httputils);

        $this->router = $router;
        $this->translator = $translator;
    }

    /**
     * Callback sur l'authentification réussie
     * @param Request $request
     * @param TokenInterface $token
     * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse|\Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response
     */
    public function onAuthenticationSuccess(Request $request, TokenInterface $token) {
        if($request->isXmlHttpRequest()){
            $data = array(
                'success'=> 1,
                'url' => $this->router->generate('fos_user_profile_show')
            );

            return new JsonResponse($data);
        }else{
            return parent::onAuthenticationSuccess($request, $token);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Définit le traducteur
     * @param \Symfony\Component\Translation\TranslatorInterface $translator
     */
    function setTranslator(TranslatorInterface $translator) {
        $this->translator = $translator;
    }
}
```

My Failure Handler :

```
    <?php

namespace JUserBundle\Handler;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\AuthenticationException;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authentication\DefaultAuthenticationFailureHandler;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernelInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\HttpUtils;
use Symfony\Component\Translation\TranslatorInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\RouterInterface;

class AuthenticationFailureHandler extends DefaultAuthenticationFailureHandler
{
    /**
     * Router
     * @var \Symfony\Component\Routing\RouterInterface
     */
    private $router;

    /**
     * Translator
     * @var \Symfony\Component\Translation\TranslatorInterface
     */
    private $translator;

    /**
     * AuthenticationFailureHandler constructor.
     * @param HttpKernelInterface $httpKernel
     * @param HttpUtils $httputils
     * @param RouterInterface $router
     * @param TranslatorInterface $translator
     */
    public function __construct(HttpKernelInterface $httpKernel, HttpUtils $httputils, RouterInterface $router, TranslatorInterface $translator)
    {
        parent::__construct($httpKernel, $httputils);

        $this->router = $router;
        $this->translator = $translator;
    }

    /**
     * Callback sur l'authentification échouée
     * @param Request $request
     * @param AuthenticationException $exception
     * @return JsonResponse|\Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse|\Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response
     */
    public function onAuthenticationFailure(Request $request, AuthenticationException $exception) {
        if($request->isXmlHttpRequest()){
            $message = $exception->getMessageKey();
            $messageTrans = $this->translator->trans($message,array(),'FOSUserBundle');
            if($messageTrans === $message){
                $messageTrans = $this->translator->trans($message,array(),'security');
            }
            $data = array(
                'message' => $messageTrans,
            );

            return new JsonResponse($data,401);
        }else{
            return parent::onAuthenticationFailure($request, $exception);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Définit le traducteur
     * @param \Symfony\Component\Translation\TranslatorInterface $translator
     */
    function setTranslator(TranslatorInterface $translator) {
        $this->translator = $translator;
    }
}
```

Many thanks for your support !

Comment: Hey Jérémie, I think you should check if the session cookie symfony sends in response to your request is getting properly set. (from what you've described - it sounds like it does not) Last time I had a similar issue was because of the cross-domain requesting, so you should make sure that the cookie domain and the domain you are using match

Comment: Thanks for your response. I checked the cookie returned and it seems to be good (if i compare with others applications). Here it is :  **REMEMBERME=SlVzZXJCdW5kbGVcRW50aXR5XFVzZXI6YW1SaGNtRjFiSFE9OjE1MTcyMTUxMDU6MWQ5YTBkNTIyZGQ1YTllNzdiNjcwZjMwMjk3NjUxN2E5YzU0YTVkYTIwMGMwMjEzZDllNTU2ZWEyMDJjZWVjOQ%3D%3D; expires=Mon, 29-Jan-2018 08:38:25 GMT; path=/; httponly**

Answer (score 0):

For persons who get same problem, i finally found the answer to my problem.
I have prefixed all my FOSUserBundle routes with /account.

The result was that the cookie generated didn't correspond to the domain i tried to log in, ie the cookie was generated for mydomain/account instead of mydomain...

So i deleted the route prefix and modify my firewall in consequence.